# Spark: Vectorassembler throws error org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe as given below. Features are `F1`, `F2`, `F3` and output variable is `Output`

```
+-----+-----+-------+------+
|   F1|F2   |F3     |0utput|
+-----+-----+-------+------+
|6.575| 4.98|   15.3|504000|
|6.421| 9.14|   17.8|453600|
|7.185| 4.03|   17.8|728700|
|6.998| 2.94|   18.7|701400|
|7.147| 5.33|   18.7|760200|
```

For apache Spark to run any ML Algorithm, we need 2 columns, features and output label. Features column is a vector combining values from all the features. For that I use vectorassembler.

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StringType, IntegerType, StructType
data_schema = [StructField('F1',IntegerType(), True),
            StructField('F2',IntegerType(),True),
             StructField('F3', IntegerType(),True),
              StructField('Output', IntegerType(),True)]
final_struc = StructType(fields=data_schema)
training=spark.read.csv('housing.csv', schema=final_struc)
vectorAssembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols = ['F1', 'F2', 'F3'], outputCol = 'features')
vhouse_df = vectorAssembler.transform(training)
vhouse_df = vhouse_df.select(['features', 'Output'])
```

WHen I want to see the vhouse_df, I get an error

```
vhouse_df.show()

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o948.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 22.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 22.0 (TID 22, 10.0.2.15, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function(VectorAssembler$$Lambda$2720/0x00000008410e0840: (struct<F1_double_VectorAssembler_becd63a80d0f:double,F2_double_VectorAssembler_becd63a80d0f:double,F3_double_VectorAssembler_becd63a80d0f:double>) => struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: can you check what is the expected datatype supposed to pass .. This could be due to datatype issue ..also

Comment: also - a quick suggestion  vhouse_df = vhouse_df.select(['features', 'OUTPUT'])
To-------

vhouse_df = vhouse_df.select('features', 'OUTPUT')

Comment: how to check which datatype to pass

Comment: Can you please check now ? The schema type has been updated ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the schema what you have provided -

In the dataset all the inpute column - F1, F2 and F3 are in double - Please change Integer to Double

```
from pyspark.sql import types as T

data_schema = T.StructType([
StructField('F1',T.DoubleType(), True),
StructField('F2',T.DoubleType(),True),
StructField('F3', T.DoubleType(),True),
StructField('Output', T.IntegerType(),True)
])
```

> Also you can try something like this - This is directly map the schema
>   from your df

```
training=spark.read.json('housing.csv', schema=df.schema)
```

Also a quick suggestion ----------

change this in your code

```
vhouse_df = vhouse_df.select(['features', 'OUTPUT'])
```

To-------

```
vhouse_df = vhouse_df.select('features', 'OUTPUT')
```

**----------UPDATE------------------**

I am not sure in case if you are looking for the below - working fine for me -

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

df = spark.read.csv('/FileStore/tables/datasets_1379_2485_housing.csv', header="true", inferSchema="true")
vectorAssembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols = ['RM', 'LSTAT', 'PTRATIO'], outputCol = 'features')
vhouse_df = vectorAssembler.transform(df)
vhouse_df.show()
```

-------OUTPUT----------

```
+-----+-----+-------+--------+------------------+
|   RM|LSTAT|PTRATIO|    MEDV|          features|
+-----+-----+-------+--------+------------------+
|6.575| 4.98|   15.3|504000.0| [6.575,4.98,15.3]|
|6.421| 9.14|   17.8|453600.0| [6.421,9.14,17.8]|
|7.185| 4.03|   17.8|728700.0| [7.185,4.03,17.8]|
|6.998| 2.94|   18.7|701400.0| [6.998,2.94,18.7]|
|7.147| 5.33|   18.7|760200.0| [7.147,5.33,18.7]|
| 6.43| 5.21|   18.7|602700.0|  [6.43,5.21,18.7]|
|6.012|12.43|   15.2|480900.0|[6.012,12.43,15.2]|
|6.172|19.15|   15.2|569100.0|[6.172,19.15,15.2]|
|5.631|29.93|   15.2|346500.0|[5.631,29.93,15.2]|
|6.004| 17.1|   15.2|396900.0| [6.004,17.1,15.2]|
|6.377|20.45|   15.2|315000.0|[6.377,20.45,15.2]|
|6.009|13.27|   15.2|396900.0|[6.009,13.27,15.2]|
|5.889|15.71|   15.2|455700.0|[5.889,15.71,15.2]|
|5.949| 8.26|   21.0|428400.0| [5.949,8.26,21.0]|
|6.096|10.26|   21.0|382200.0|[6.096,10.26,21.0]|
|5.834| 8.47|   21.0|417900.0| [5.834,8.47,21.0]|
|5.935| 6.58|   21.0|485100.0| [5.935,6.58,21.0]|
| 5.99|14.67|   21.0|367500.0| [5.99,14.67,21.0]|
|5.456|11.69|   21.0|424200.0|[5.456,11.69,21.0]|
|5.727|11.28|   21.0|382200.0|[5.727,11.28,21.0]|
+-----+-----+-------+--------+------------------+
```

Comment: I get same error even now after doing `vhouse_df = vhouse_df.select('features', 'OUTPUT')`

Comment: How to change to double?

Comment: Please check - Answer has been updated -  Please do not forget to approve the answer once it worked.. Thanking you in advance ..

Comment: hi. i did the exact same things as above, changing to double and removing square brackets. still does not work... im upvoting for youe efforts but cannt accept as answer as it doesnt solve my problem

Comment: okay.. this depends on how your json has been structured - can you share how the json input looks like ?

Comment: let me change that line to read.csv, since there is no json as such, still same result

Comment: link of the file is `https://www.kaggle.com/schirmerchad/bostonhoustingmlnd`

Comment: vhouse_df = vhouse_df.select('features', 'MEDV)